# A matrix ring over $\mathbb{C}$ is also a Frobenius algebra over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, monoidal-categories, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am new to the Frobenius Algebra course. One of my textbook exercises ask to prove:

A matrix ring over $\mathbb{C}$ is also a Frobenius algebra over $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt:

I know that I can give a Frobenius form (i.e, nullspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ contains no nontrivial left ideal)  $ \epsilon_{1}: M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}$ by trace map, but I can't see why it is a Frobenius using definition that  nullspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ contains no nontrivial left ideal.

Further, I can give a Frobenius form, $\epsilon_{2}:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ by sending $a+ib$ to $a$. this is trivially a Frobenius form as field $\mathbb{C}$ have no nontrivial ideals.

Actual Question:

Now in order to show that there is a Frobenius form $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{R}$, I want to show $\epsilon_{1} \circ \epsilon_{2}$ is a required Frobenius form.

Any solution/reference will be a great help!!

Further could you please refer to some elementary book on Frobenius algebra other than a book by "Joachim Kock" (which is not elementary for me, it skips a lot of things)

Comment: You seem to be a little confused on this point: *using definition that  nullspace of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ contains no nontrivial left ideal.* You are not using a nullspace of the matrix ring (whatever that is.) You are using the nullspace **of the form**. That means the set of all $b\in R$ such that $\mathrm{tr}(a,b)=0$ for all $a\in R$.  Later, you think the nullspace is a right ideal in $\mathbb C$ which is again the wrong setting.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let's show that $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ is a Frobenius algebra over $\mathbb{C}$.

Any non-trivial left ideal will contain a non-zero matrix $b\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$.  We need to find a matrix $a\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that ${\rm tr}(ab)\neq 0$, thus proving that the left ideal does not lie in the nullspace of tr.

Multiplication by a matrix on the left corresponds to row operations.  As $b\neq 0$ we know some entry $b_{ij}\neq 0$.  So pick $a$ so that left multiplication by $a$ takes the $i^{\rm th}$ row to the $j^{\rm th}$ row, and makes every other row $0$.  Explicitly $a_{ji}=1$ and every other entry of $a$ is zero.

Then ${\rm tr}(ab)=b_{ij}\neq 0$ as required.

Now consider the form coming from the map $x\mapsto {\rm Re(tr(}x))$.  We repeat the above argument, now taking $a_{ji}=\overline{b_{ij}}$, and all other entries of $a$ equal to $0$.  Then ${\rm tr}(ab)=|b_{ij}|^2\neq 0$, as required.